# Set Order for a Table (Laravel)

Tags: laravel

I using laravel 5.1 and PostgreSQL.

I have data product, and I want to custom the order by myself.

For example, I have product

```
{A, B, C, D, E, F}
```

and I want to show them in a table by what I want

```
Idx | Item
-----------
1   | A
2   | C
3   | E
4   | B
5   | F
6   | D
```

To do this I need a page that can setting it right?
My problem is I don't know what page must I develop to create setting order.

Maybe a page that has a table that I can move each row to set the order,
and a database field in item table to save the order setting?

Please someone help me, is there a plugin like that?

Comment: why dont you just add an extra column on your product table call "custom_index" and manipulate it just like all the other column that u already had

Comment: ya, i think like that, but how to create the setting page? a product table with a index textbox? i have 100 item data, i cant change every textbox with number, it takes time and it can double index value maybe @crystalwill

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a page that list all items with minimal amount of information. Then you change the order use something like [jQuery UI sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/) or [Dargsort](https://dragsort.codeplex.com/) to sort them, and then save the index of the list  back to your database as custom index

But keep in mind 100 items is still too many, it would be much better to just provide filter of all attributes to display items in different order.